# Git output "Submodule registered for path" mixed with aliases config

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-alias, git-for-windows

*(Originally asked [on Git mailing list](https://public-inbox.org/git/CABUeae_N3NFXn-E1+LHORL3RDf5iTCFn=zyuOo3c2Aot2QF7pg@mail.gmail.com/) and [on Git For Windows mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/git-for-windows/XqrfaEQpd1E/mJyXuxO-BAAJ), so far without any response.)*

### Problem

While running `git clone --recurse-submodules https://repo` command, I noticed a strange output from `git` command during initialisation of submodules:

```
Submodule 'Binary/A' (https://repo) registered for path '!f() { ~/AppData/Local/Fork/Fork.exe $PWD; }; fBinary/A'
Submodule 'Binary/B' (https://repo) registered for path '!sh -c 'git log $1@{1}..$1@{0} $@'Binary/B'
Submodule 'Binary/C' (https://repo) registered for path 'ls-files -o -i --exclude-standardBinary/C'
Submodule 'Binary/D' (https://repo) registered for path 'mergetool.TortoiseGitMerge.trustexitcodeBinary/D'
```

The command seems to run well and completes with success though.

### Partial diagnosis

I managed to identify what is that garbage injected into the printed paths of submodules. It comes from git aliases I have got configured, for example, in `~/.gitconfig` there is this include:

```
[include]
path = ~/alias_misc.gitconfig
```

and in `~/alias_misc.gitconfig` there is this alias

```
[alias]
fapp = "!f() { ~/AppData/Local/Fork/Fork.exe $PWD; }; f"
```

which is inserted into `Binary/A` path in the `git clone` output copied above.

(All the files are [available on GitHub](https://github.com/mloskot/wsl-config/tree/master/git)).

### Question

Could anyone explain why `git` randomly inserts definitions of aliases in its output?

Is there anything wrong with my Git configuration files?

Comment: Sure looks like a bug. There were related bugs in the submodule output in git 2.17 if I recall correctly...

Comment: @torek That's what I suspected, so thanks for confirming that. I'll wait a bit more and submit a bug report.

Answer (score 1):

TL;TR: It was a bug in Git, fixed in 2.21.

I've received [response to my original post](https://public-inbox.org/git/20190221041756.GA28389@sigill.intra.peff.net/) on Git mailing list:

> Certainly we fixed a bunch of getenv() problems in the upcoming 2.21 release, including 8aac69038f (get_super_prefix(): copy getenv() result, 2019-01-11).

I've verified the problem no longer occurs in git version 2.21.0.rc2.windows.1